ModuleNotFound Cython in powershell while installing dependencies but I can import Cython
I installed it via
python -m pip install Cython

I can do:

But then, when I try to install pycocotools by running
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI

I get an error while setuptools is installing the dependencies:
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting git+https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git@cocodataset-master#subdirectory=PythonAPI
  Cloning https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git (to revision cocodataset-master) to c:\users\irema\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-0h906wf7
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git 'C:\Users\irema\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-0h906wf7'
  Running command git checkout -b cocodataset-master --track origin/cocodataset-master
  branch 'cocodataset-master' set up to track 'origin/cocodataset-master'.
  Switched to a new branch 'cocodataset-master'
  Resolved https://github.com/gautamchitnis/cocoapi.git to commit 20291f19c46a8d11935862bc9e449a1b72ec25ed
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\irema\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pv2h8be6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\irema\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pv2h8be6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\irema\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pv2h8be6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\irema\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-pv2h8be6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I also tried:
python -m pip install setuptools
python -m pip install --upgrade Cython

but that did not change anything. What am I missing? I'm not using any virtual environments:
PS C:\Users\irema> (Get-command python).Path
C:\Users\irema\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

